# TSQL select into Temp table from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

This seems relatively simple, but apparently it's not.

I need to create a temp table based on an existing table via the select into syntax:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE FROM EXISTING_TABLE
```

The problem is, the existing table name is accepted via a parameter...

I can get the table's data via:

```
execute ('SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName)
```

but how do I marry the two so that I can put the results from the execute directly into the temp table.

The columns for each table that this is going to be used for are not the same so building the temp table before getting the data is not practical.

I'm open to any suggestions except using a global temp table.

**Update:**

This is completely ridiculous, BUT my reservations with the global temp table is that this is a multi user platform lends itself to issues if the table will linger for long periods of time...

Sooo.. just to get past this part I've started by using the execute to generate a global temp table.

```
execute('select * into ##globalDynamicFormTable from ' + @tsFormTable)
```

I then use the global temp table to load the local temp table:

```
select * into #tempTable from ##globalDynamicFormTable
```

I then drop the global table.

```
drop table ##globalDynamicFormTable
```

this is dirty and I don't like it, but for the time being, until i get a better solution, its going to have to work.

**In the End:**

I guess there is no way to get around it.

The best answer appears to be either;

Create a **view** in the execute command and use that to load the local temp table in the stored procedure.

Create a **global temp table** in the execute command and use that to load the local temp table.

With that said i'll probably just stick with the global temp table because creating and dropping views is audited in my organization, and I'm sure they are going to question that if it starts happening all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A working example.

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'YourTableName'

EXECUTE ('SELECT * INTO #TEMP  FROM ' + @TableName +'; SELECT * FROM #TEMP;')
```

Second solution with accessible temp table

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'

EXECUTE ('CREATE VIEW vTemp AS
        SELECT *
        FROM ' + @TableName)
SELECT * INTO #TEMP  FROM vTemp 

--DROP THE VIEW HERE      
DROP VIEW vTemp

/*START USING TEMP TABLE
************************/
--EX:
SELECT * FROM #TEMP


--DROP YOUR TEMP TABLE HERE
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Second SELECT in after the INSERT is to show that you could query the data just inserted into the #TEMP table.

Comment: but creating the temp table in the execute puts the temp table completely out of scope... try doing a select from the temp table outside of the execute command... it won't work.

Comment: declare vartablename as varchar(100)
select vartablename = 'collateral'
execute ('select * into #temp from ' + vartablename)
select * from #temp       results in - Invalid object name '#temp'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that "Invalid object name " issue if you use it out of the execute command. You can query #TEMP within the execute string as I did. Not sure what you need to do after filling the temp table..

Comment: @RajMore of course it works, but it doesnt work for what I need it for.  it puts the temp table out of scope. as you can see from my 2nd response to the original comment.

Comment: @Indikaf I'm going to be inserting values into the temp table based on the business process in the stored procedure from a list of values sent in as a string, and then ill be using the temp table to insert back into the original table.

Comment: Is inserting back into original table happening in the same stored procedure? Can you give us an example of what you do after filling temp table?

Comment: yes, it is going to happen in the same stored procedure.  the temp table is being retrieved schema only.  once the temp table is built, i split out the deliminated values that were created app using a dictionary.  the dictionary contains key value pairs that have the column for the table, and the value for the column.  i'm then building an instert statment using those columns/values to be inserted into the temp table to do additional work before inserting back into the original table

Comment: OK here we go again. This is again working and you can access the temp table as you wish. 


EXECUTE ('CREATE VIEW vTemp AS
            SELECT *
            FROM ' + @YourTableName)
SELECT * INTO #TEMP  FROM vTemp 

--DROP THE VIEW HERE      
DROP VIEW vTemp

/*DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE 
************************/
--EX:
SELECT * FROM #TEMP

/*END OF YOUR JOB */

--DROP YOUR TEMP TABLE HERE
DROP TABLE #TEMP

Comment: i see.  its pretty much the same thing as creating a global temp table and loading it from there... i think the moral of the story is... you can't make a temp table from a dynamic select w/o getting your hands dirty.  +1 for sticking with it and coming up with a viable answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @sql varchar(100);

declare @tablename as varchar(100);

select @tablename = 'your_table_name';

create table #tmp 
    (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

set @sql = 'select aa, bb, cc from ' + @tablename;

insert into #tmp(col1, col2, col3) exec( @sql );

select * from #tmp;
```

Comment: It had an error (need parentheses around @sql), and did not create the sample table to select from, but the general approach does in fact work.  I have corrected these issues.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it with a pivot in dynamic sql (#AccPurch was created prior to this)

```
DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(MAX)
declare @Month Nvarchar(1000)

--DROP TABLE #temp
select distinct YYYYMM into #temp from #AccPurch AS ap
SELECT  @Month = COALESCE(@Month, '') + '[' + CAST(YYYYMM AS VarChar(8)) + '],' FROM    #temp

SELECT   @Month= LEFT(@Month,len(@Month)-1)


SET @sql = N'SELECT UserID, '+ @Month + N' into ##final_Donovan_12345 FROM (
Select ap.AccPurch ,
       ap.YYYYMM ,
       ap.UserID ,
       ap.AccountNumber
FROM #AccPurch AS ap 
) p
Pivot (SUM(AccPurch) FOR YYYYMM IN ('+@Month+ N')) as pvt'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql

Select * INTO #final From ##final_Donovan_12345

DROP TABLE  ##final_Donovan_12345

Select * From #final AS f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @count_ser_temp int;
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'TableTemporal'

EXECUTE ('CREATE VIEW vTemp AS
    SELECT *
    FROM ' + @TableTemporal)
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #servicios_temp  FROM vTemp

DROP VIEW vTemp

-- Contar la cantidad de registros de la tabla temporal
SELECT @count_ser_temp = COUNT(*) FROM #servicios_temp;

-- Recorro los registros de la tabla temporal 
WHILE @count_ser_temp > 0
 BEGIN
 END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. I'm not sure how many columns the executed query returned. So I created a temp table with a single column and changed it using a dynamic execute query.

I got the idea from [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/using-temp-table-in-sql-server-and-adding-columns-dynamically/). Instead of using a while loop, I used COALESCE to create a single comma-separated column.

Please feel free to make suggestions or ask questions.

```
-- Temp table you want to access after dynamic insert
drop table if exists #TempTable
create table #TempTable (ID int)

DECLARE @ColNames nvarchar(max), @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max)

-- query to create dynamic columns you need
SELECT @ColNames = COALESCE(@ColNames + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' NVARCHAR(max) NULL'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'

-- alter script to add column to temp table
SET @DynamicSQL = 'ALTER TABLE #TempTable ADD ' + @ColNames

-- add dynamic columns to temp table
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

-- execute the query and result will be in #temptable
insert into #TempTable
execute('select 1 as ID,* from TABLE_NAME') 

select * from #TempTable
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), and do something like:

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMPTABLE FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI'
     , 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName)
```

Comment: there are pemissions issues that keep open rowset from working, not to mention that with 3 different environments, id have to make sure that every time this solution is deployed that its using the correct connection string for the openrowset.

Comment: This doesnt work - you cannot pass variables to OpenRowset