# Switch case with storing results into same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to store the results into table with same name as per the condition. How to achieve the same ? Following is the code:
While executing it throws error that #a already exists.

```
IF @Input ='1'
        BEGIN
                drop #a
                SELECT *
                INTO #a
                FROM table1
        END;

    ELSE IF @Input ='2'
        BEGIN
                drop #a
                SELECT *
                INTO #a
                FROM table2
        END;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution using a [global temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server) (***maybe not the best / safest solution***). The statements get executed with [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(20) = '1'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##a') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##a 
  END

IF @Input = '1'
    EXEC ('SELECT * INTO ##a FROM table1;') 
ELSE IF @Input = '2'
    EXEC ('SELECT * INTO ##a FROM table2;')

-- you can implement steps here to create a local temporary table.
-- see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534990/tsql-select-into-temp-table-from-dynamic-sql

SELECT * FROM ##a
```

Also have a look at this question: [TSQL select into Temp table from dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534990/tsql-select-into-temp-table-from-dynamic-sql). There is also described how you can get the data as local temporary table in two different ways (using a global temporary table or a view).

The problem using the `EXECUTE` function is leaving the scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if object_id('tempdb..#a') is not null 
   drop table #a

    IF @Input ='1'
            BEGIN
                    SELECT *
                    INTO #a
                    FROM table1
            END;
        ELSE IF @Input ='2'
            BEGIN
                    SELECT *
                    INTO #a
                    FROM table2
            END;
```

Comment: What is the difference?