# How do I Create a local temp table with the 'Select Into' function with the source tables text Name and not the table object

Tags: sql, sql-insert, temp-tables

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.
I am creating a dynamic table value reading script.
I only need to read and collect specific values in each of the tables.

1. Collect the tables `#xPropTableListTempTable`
2. Loop through each table and collect the required columns `#xPropColumnListTempTable`
   Every thing works but the last step.... Collecting the values from each table **Issue**

**Tables**

1. I don't how many tables are used to support the capability.
2. I do know the naming pattern of the tables: `XPROPERTYVALUES`, `XPROPERTYVALUES1`, `XPROPERTYVALUES2`, ....
3. I can get a list of the table text names from the view `information_schema.tables`
4. I can insert the Table names into a local temp `#table` to iterate through

**Columns**

1. In each table I do not know the number of columns.
2. I do know the naming pattern of the columns I need: `'%$is_Defined'`
3. I can get a list of the columns names from the view `information_schema.columns`
4. I can insert the columns names into a local temp `#columns` to iterate through

**Issue**

Dynamically Collecting the values from each table

I can't create a temp `#table`, or instantiate a table object, using the table text names.

**I did try and did not work:**

```
Declare @tempTableCreateStr as nVarchar(max)
set @tempTableCreateStr = 'Select * Into #xPropValueTempTable From ' + @tableName + ' Where item_id = ''' + @itemGUID + ''''
Print @tempTableCreateStr
Exec sp_executesql @tempTableCreateStr
```

But then I read a post that stated that Exec can not perform the  `Select Into` function.
So I can't perform this step:

```
SELECT @propertyValue = STUFF((Select ', ' + @propertyName 
                From  
                  (Select @propertyName, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By property_value_column) as Row  
                   From #xPropValueTempTable  
                  ) as TMP3 
                for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

**Also tried:**

[TSQL select into Temp table from dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534990/tsql-select-into-temp-table-from-dynamic-sql)

```
--Set @tempTableViewCreateStr = 'Select * Into #xPropValueTempTable From ' + @tableName + ' Where item_id = ''' + @itemGUID + ''''
--Set @tempTableViewCreateStr = 'Create View xPropValueTempView Select * From ' + @tableName + ' Where item_id = ''' + @itemGUID + ''''
Set @tempTableViewCreateStr = 'Create View xPropValueTempView Select * From ' + @tableName 
Print @tempTableViewCreateStr
Exec (@tempTableViewCreateStr)

Select * Into #xPropValueTempTable From xPropValueTempView --Where item_id = @itemGUID
Drop View xPropValueTempView
```

**Error**

```
In Table:[xp].XPROPERTYVALUES
Create View xPropValueTempView Select * From [xp].XPROPERTYVALUES
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure xPropValueTempView, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 56
Invalid object name 'xPropValueTempView'.
```

Comment: What is your end goal here?